# Problems enabling HDMI screen framebuffer on startup for ts_calibrate

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I'm running [EGT](https://github.com/linux4sam/egt/) on a SAMA5D4 Xplained board. It uses KMS for output to a HDMI screen. I've got a touchscreen that needs to be calibrated on the first use, I'm using ts_calibrate from tslib. I have a small script to check if the screen has already been calibrated & if not it attempts to enable the screen & run ts_calibrate.

The script works fine when I'm logged in normally but I get a blank screen after startup when invoked by crontab by:

@reboot /usr/share/myProject/startEGT.sh

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Startup script to launch calibration settings for touchscreen & start application

CAL_FILE=/etc/pointercal

if [ ! -f "$CAL_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Didn't find screen calibartion file"
    
    # Force screen on
    echo "1" > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/state    
    echo "U:1024x600p-0" > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode
    until [ $(cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/state) = "1" ]
    do
        echo "1" > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/state
        echo "U:1024x600p-0" > /sys/class/graphics/fb0/mode
        # cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/state
        sleep 2
    done
    
    export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
    ts_calibrate

fi

echo "Calibration file found"
# TODO: Need to check if ts_uinput already running
ts_uinput -d -v
EGT_INPUT_DEVICES=libinput:/dev/input/touchscreen0 EGT_SCREEN_SIZE=1024x600 /usr/share/myProject/startEGTproject
```

I suspect the issue is something to do with a filesystem not mounted or something not ready but thats a guess. Anyone have any pointers?